# Netbeans 11.2 Source/Design tab missing

Tags: java, netbeans

Working with Netbeans 11.2.
After creating a JFrame Form (an IDE created class extending JFame), the design view isn't available(where one drag-and-drops swing components onto the frame). This wasn't the case in Netbeans 10 where a tab was available to switch between design or code.

Am I missing something? Is there a special setting which needs to be enabled or is this a bug?

**Env**
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2
Java: 12.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 12.0.1+12
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 12.0.1+12

Answer (score 0):

Apparently its disabled by default. Enable via

View-->Show Editor Toolbar